# Selecting multiple sheet names in the list box and returning the results in msgbox

Tags: excel, vba

i tried various methods to select multiple sheets in the list box and returning the selected sheet names into the msgbox. can any one help doing this.

currently i am able to populate the sheet names in the list box.However i am not getting the all selected sheet names in the msgbox.

```
Public listChoice As String

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

For n = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    With ListBox1
        .AddItem ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(n).Name
    End With
Next n

End Sub


Private Sub ListBox1_AfterUpdate()

listChoice = ListBox1.Text

End Sub



Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
MsgBox (listChoice)
End Sub
```

Comment: look at the selected property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the selected item in a listbox isn't as straightforward as you'd want it to be:

```
  Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
      Dim Msg As String
      Dim i As Integer
      Msg = "You selected" & vbNewLine
      For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
          If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
              Msg = Msg & ListBox1.List(i) & vbNewLine
          End If
      Next i
      MsgBox Msg
  End Sub
```

credit: http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/Forms/GettheselecteditemsinaListBox.htm

You don't need the `ListBox1_AfterUpdate()` Sub or the public `listChoice` variable with this code

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Nope, the change event does however.

Comment: @ CallumDA, Thanks a lot this is what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

This msgbox the selected items in listbox.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
        Msg = ListBox1.List(i) & vbNewLine
    End If
Next i
MsgBox Msg
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may assist,

```
Private strOP As String
Private dicSelections As Scripting.Dictionary

Private Sub ListBox1_Mouseup(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

Dim strSheet As String

    strSheet = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex)

    If Me.ListBox1.Selected(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex) Then
        If Not dicSelections.Exists(strSheet) Then
            dicSelections.Add strSheet, strSheet
        Else
        End If
    Else
        If dicSelections.Exists(strSheet) Then
            dicSelections.Remove strSheet
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()
Me.ListBox1.AddItem "one"
Me.ListBox1.AddItem "two"
Me.ListBox1.AddItem "three"
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Debug.Print "Worksheets selected " &  Join(dicSelections.Items(), " & ")
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set dicSelections = New Scripting.Dictionary
End Sub
```